# How do I get "Page Attributes" option in Cocoa print dialog?

Tags: cocoa, printing, nsprintoperation

The program I'm writing runs under OS X 10.5 Leopard. My target has its Base SDK and Deployment Target both set to Mac OS X 10.5. When I initiate printing, my print dialog doesn't show the Page Attributes option in which the user can select page size and orientation.

[image: No Page Attributes]

Other programs running under Leopard do show this option:

[image: Yes Page Attributes]

Here's the code that initiates printing:

```
-(void)print {
    NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
    TemperaturePressurePrintView *printView = [[TemperaturePressurePrintView alloc] initWithFrequencies:frequencies];
    if (printView) {
        [[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:printView printInfo:printInfo] runOperation];
        [printView release];
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get Page Attributes to show up in my print dialog?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was a tough thing to search for because the results were mostly about using the print panel, not programming one. I finally found a clue [on Cocoabuilder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/206512-changing-nsprintpanel-ui-in-10-5.html) where it mentions `NSPrintPanelOptions` and `NSPrintPanel`'s `-setOptions:` method.

This code accomplishes what I need:

```
-(void)print {
    NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
    TemperaturePressurePrintView *printView = [[TemperaturePressurePrintView alloc] initWithFrequencies:frequencies];
    if (printView) {
        NSPrintOperation *op = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:printView printInfo:printInfo];
        [[op printPanel] setOptions:[[op printPanel] options] | NSPrintPanelShowsPageSetupAccessory];
        [op runOperation];
        [printView release];
    }
}
```

Comment: important to note that this snippet is a drop-in replacement for the standard [myView print:nil]; operation, except that it lets you customize the print dialog first.  Great, clear solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a few years after the original answer and macOS Sierra seems to have introduced a bug into the behaviour of panels that have the 'NSPrintPanelShowsPageSetupAccessory' option set. Invalid values, such as a ridiculously large scale, cause crashes instead of displaying an alert sheet.

Fortunately there is a workaround. Using

```
NSPrintPanelShowsPaperSize | NSPrintPanelShowsOrientation | NSPrintPanelShowsScaling
```

instead seems to result in a panel that works fine.